# How to check whether I have entered all the necessary numbers in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have entered numbers 1-1074 in an excel sheet and I want to check whether I have missed any number in that range. How would I be able to check that?

Comment: Do you want to know if any are missing, or which numbers are missing.  Finding if any are missing is easy.  Returning a list of missing numbers is a little more difficult.

Comment: I assume this is sequential. Did you just do A2=A1+1, then drag it down?

Comment: Or type `1` in `A1` and `CTRL`-drag down

Answer (score 0):

This macro should work even if the entries are not sorted:

```
Sub DataCheck()
    Dim A As Range, i As Long, msg As String, r As Range
    msg = ""
    Set A = Range("A:A")

    For i = 1 To 1074
        Set r = A.Find(what:=CStr(i), After:=A(1), lookat:=xlWhole)
        If r Is Nothing Then
            msg = msg & vbCrLf & i
        End If
    Next i

    If msg = "" Then
        MsgBox "nothing missing"
    Else
        MsgBox "These are missing:" & msg
    End If
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you just need a Yes/No answer, then this formula should return TRUE/FALSE for you:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(COUNTIF(myRange,ROW(INDIRECT("1:1074")))>0))=1074
```